# Is there a way to return multiple values to python after a MySql query?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am new to python and of course MySql. I recently created a Python function that generates a list of values that i want to insert to a table (2 columns) in MySql based on their specification.

Is it possible to create a procedure that can take a list of values that i'm sending through python, check if these values are already in one of my 2 two columns,

- if they are already in the second one don't return,
- if they are in the first one return all that are contained there
- if they are in none of them return them with some kind of a flag so i can handle them through python and insert them to correct table

**EXTRA EXPLANATION**

Let me try to explain what i want to achieve so maybe you can give me a push and help me out. So, first i get a list of CPE items like this ("cpe:/a:apache:iotdb:0.9.0") in python and my goal is to save them into a database where the CPE's related to the IOT will be differentiated from the generic ones and saved in different tables or columns. My goal is that this distinction will be done by user input for each and every item **but only once per item**, so after parsing all items in python i want to first check in database if they exist in one of the tables or columns.

So **for each and every list item** that i pass i want to query mysql and:

- if it exists in **non iot** column already don't return anything
- if it exist in **iot** column already return item
- if **not exists anywhere** return also item so i can get user input in python to verify if this is iot item or not and insert it to database after that

Comment: *Is it possible to create a procedure that* Inclear - python or MySQL procedure?

Comment: Your explanation is really unclear. Could you give examples of data and the expected results? The answer to "is it possible" is almost certainly yes. Do the query, fetch the results, and use `if` statements.

Comment: Show an example of table data (3-4 rows) and 3 variants of "list of values" matched all 3 variants mentioned.

Comment: *if they are already in the second one don't return* ALL of them? at least one? something else? *if they are in the first one return all that are contained there* i.e. drop non-existing values from the list? *if ... if ... if ...* Does this means "if ... else if ... else if ..."?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use library called pandas.
Idk if it is the best solution but it could work.
Export the thing you have in SQL into pandas or just query the SQL file using pandas.
Check out this library, it's really helpful for exploring data sets.

https://pandas.pydata.org/